# Is a Migraton of a Synology VDSM with volume bigger than 2TB to another NAS even possible? If yes, how?

Tags: virtual-machine, synology

So I am using a RS3618xs with Synology DSM 6.2.4 and I'm trying to export and migrate a synology VDSM to another Synology NAS, with a volume bigger than the given 2TB. So far, I had no success. I tried to build a raw image with dd, i tried to manually move the directories,even tried manually starting the export via console commands, but so far, everything failed. Is there a way to accomplish this or am I fighting windmills?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so a co-worker found the solution to this problem by mere coincidence.

We discovered that Synology builds its VMs from an OVF file containing the machine itself and 3 vmdk files containing the partitions of said machine. Since those are no directories it is possible to move them to another NAS using cp sparse.

So we did exactly this. We build an identical VM on the other NAS system, configured it once and then replaced the three partitions with the ones we copied from the original on using cp sparse.
It kept the configurations of the original VDSM and the installed apps and the data are all intact and usable.